# How to set blank space after a table in a docx document (working with apache poi)

Tags: apache-poi, openxml, docx

I've been trying to create tables and make them to leave some space between its bottom border and whatever comes after the table (usually text).

As far as I have crawl through ooxml specification I understand that I need to add to the table this chain of elements tblPr (table properties) -> tblpPr (table position properties), and set the attribute bottomFromText to the specific amount space I want between the table and the next element, also the vertAnchor attribute (right now I'm configuring this with the "text" value) and finally the tblpY attribute.

A q&d snippet of what I'm doing is this (java and apache poi):

```
XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
CTTblPr _cttblpr = table.getCTTbl().addNewTblPr();

_cttblpr.addNewTblpPr().setBottomFromText(BigInteger.valueOf(284));
_cttblpr.getTblpPr().setVertAnchor(STVAnchor.TEXT);
_cttblpr.getTblpPr().setTblpY(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
```

My main reference has been [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablepositionproperties.aspx). Also I have been creating (with LibreOffice writer and Microsoft Office 2007) simple documents with just a table and the space I want and extracting the files inside it (word/document.xml specifically) to see in place this. All my efforts to achieve this have been unsuccessful by now.

Do you know what is wrong here? I strongly believe I have missconcepts...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you need **w:bottomFromText**, for example:

```
            <w:tbl>
                <w:tblPr>
                    <w:tblpPr w:leftFromText="187" w:rightFromText="187" w:bottomFromText="4320" w:vertAnchor="text" w:tblpY="1"/>
                    <w:tblOverlap w:val="never"/>
                </w:tblPr>
```

Based on the above, your code looks plausible.

For comparison, if you were doing it with **docx4j**, you'd create that in one of 2 ways.

The first way is to explicitly use the JAXB object factory:

org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory wmlObjectFactory = new org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory();

```
Tbl tbl = wmlObjectFactory.createTbl(); 
JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Tbl> tblWrapped = wmlObjectFactory.createBodyTbl(tbl); 
    // Create object for tblPr
    TblPr tblpr = wmlObjectFactory.createTblPr(); 
    tbl.setTblPr(tblpr); 
        // Create object for tblpPr
        CTTblPPr tblppr = wmlObjectFactory.createCTTblPPr(); 
        tblpr.setTblpPr(tblppr); 
            tblppr.setLeftFromText( BigInteger.valueOf( 187) ); 
            tblppr.setRightFromText( BigInteger.valueOf( 187) ); 
            tblppr.setBottomFromText( BigInteger.valueOf( 4320) ); 
            tblppr.setVertAnchor(org.docx4j.wml.STVAnchor.TEXT);
            tblppr.setTblpY( BigInteger.valueOf( 1) ); 
        // Create object for tblOverlap
        CTTblOverlap tbloverlap = wmlObjectFactory.createCTTblOverlap(); 
        tblpr.setTblOverlap(tbloverlap); 
            tbloverlap.setVal(org.docx4j.wml.STTblOverlap.NEVER);
```

The second is to unmarshall a string:

```
    String openXML = "<w:tbl xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\">
                      + "<w:tblPr>
                            + "<w:tblpPr w:bottomFromText=\"4320\" w:leftFromText=\"187\" w:rightFromText=\"187\" w:tblpY=\"1\" w:vertAnchor=\"text\"/>"
                                + "<w:tblOverlap w:val=\"never\"/>"
                          +"</w:tblPr>"
etc    
                +"</w:tbl>";
    Tbl tbl = (Tbl)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(openXML);
```

Comment: First I want to thanks your answer. First approach is more or less what I am doing, second approach is quite dirty, I try not to hardcode things in my code, this is supposed to be maintenable xD